# Compiz Window Picker plugin for XFCE4?

Tags: xfce, window-manager

Is there a separate window picker software (like the one in Compiz or `Present Window` in KDE4) ? I'm running xfce4

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean: is there another software besides KWIN or Compiz that can be used for openGL features in xfce4?

Well, why not use KWIN as your window manager in xfce4?

1. just install KWIN with its dependencies (don't download recommended files with that or KDE will come down - which you don't want).
2. run KWIN with the command `kwin --replace` and, Bob's your uncle, you'll have all those features and effects available within xfce.
3. You can change the which features you use by clicking on the menu icon on the titlebar, and go to: 
   More actions>Window Manager Settings..>

You will find that KWIN works very smoothly in Xfce

Answer (score 0):

You may like [xfdashboard](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/applications/xfdashboard/start), which is

> Maybe a Gnome shell like dashboard for Xfce

It should provide you some really nice graphics for picking and moving windows. A program launcher with shortcuts is included, too.